# Can we assume a form of heteroskedasticity and correlation within groups with the sample mean?

Tags: correlation, sampling, inference, mean, standard-error

Correlation between errors and hetereoskadacity typically come up with regression, but can these same concepts come into play with the sample mean? I know hetereoskadacity itself does not make sense since it is about conditional variances, but I could think of each X$_i$ having its own variance, and that within sum subgroups, the X$_i$'s are correlated. so for example, say I have a geographic group g, so I can label my X's as X$_{i,g}$, and I assume Var(X$_{i,g}$) = $\sigma_i^2$, and for each observation within a given group g, cov(x$_{i,g}$, X$_{j,g}$) $\neq$ 0?

In which case, the variance of X$_i$ would become (for simplicity, assume g and g' are the only reasons, with two observations in each just because I can't think of the concise way to write this as a summation)

$\sigma_{1,g}^2$ + $\sigma_{2,g}^2$ + cov(x$_{1,g}$,x$_{j,g}$)  + $\sigma_{1,g'}^2$ + $\sigma_{2,g'}^2$ + cov(x$_{1,g'}$,x$_{j,g'}$).

Does this logic even make sense, theoretically and practically? For regression it is obvious that it is, but is there a real life application where this is the case, and how does this influence on sample t tests, confidence intervals for the sample mean etc. Is it something that can conceivable occur with a non 'simple random sample' for example for stratified samples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimation of the sample mean is equivalent to estimating the coefficient of an intercept-only model. Consequently, if you have violations of the usual $iid$ assumption when you calculate the sample mean, I see no reason not to apply standard tricks like Newey-West corrections. Your estimation, after all, is just another regression.